# How do list.map wait request response?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a map with request inside, but I detected the map don't wait the request response to get next index.

```
this.products = [];
productList.map((product) => {
this.productService.getProductInfo(product).subscribe(productData => {
   productData.selected = true;
   this.products.push(productData);
  });
});
```

there's a way do the map wait the request response?

Comment: What do you mean by get the next index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist I'd make an array of requests:

```
const productRequests: Observable<Product>[] = productList.map(productId => this.productService.getProductInfo(productId));
```

then next you combine the observables, you do multiple ways, I assume perservering the order is important

```
// loads all at once, preserves order
forkJoin(...productRequests).subscribe(productData => {
  this.products = productData;
});
```

or

```
// loads one by one, sort post result to preserve order
this.products = [];
merge(...productRequests).subscribe(productData => {
  this.products.push(productData);
  this.products.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.id < b.id) {
      return -1
    }
    if (a.id > b.id) {
      return 1
    }
    return 0;
  });
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-map-request